# Separability of $f(x) = (x-1)^2(x-3)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots

This is an example in Ash, Basic Abstract Algebra, ch.3.4 page 73 at the bottom (or [here](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/Algebra/Chapter3.pdf) on page 11). It states that

> $f(x) = (x-1)^2(x-3)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is separable.

But, $f'(x) = 2(x-1)(x-3) + (x-1)^2 = (x-1)(3x-7)$ so that $\gcd(f,f') = x-1$.  That is, $\deg(\gcd(f,f'))=1$.  From the proposition in Ash, 3.4.2 (or prop 33, sec.13.5 in Dummit&Foote), $f(x)$ is separable if and only if it's relatively prime to its derivative.

I must be missing something here.  Can someone please explain why/how the above $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}$ is separable over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Thank you very much for your effort.

Answer (score 4):

The definition of separability is that an **irreducible** polynomial is separable iff it has no repeated roots in a splitting field. A criterion for having no repeated roots is given by the lemma involving the derivative, which you stated.

But your $f$ is **not** irreducible. For an **arbitrary** (possibly reducible) polynomial, we say that it is separable if all of its irreducible factors are separable (i.e. have no repeated roots). Therefore you should have applied the lemma not to $f$, but to the irreducible factors of $f$, which are given by $x-1$ and $x-3$ (however these are clearly irreducible, also without appealing to that lemma).

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation between the two possibilities!

Answer (score 2):

The definition of a separable polynomial in Ash 3.4.2 (which you reference) refers to an **irreducible** polynomial. Your $f(x)$ is completely reduced to linear factors over $\mathbb Q$. Each of these factors is separable. And, as Ash explains, a polynomial which is the product of separable factors is itself separable.

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation between the two possibilities!